# Symfony - get module URL-key

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1

I'm using a common set of javascript across several Symfony modules.  I'd like to output the current module url-key as a javascript variable, so the javascript can use it to construct urls for various AJAX calls.  I can't find where to get it, though.

```
$sf_context->getModuleName();
```

returns the module name, but not how it appears in the URL.  I get that I could parse the module name from window.location, but that not only seems a bit crude, but I will soon have a case where I construct a url to a different module than the one that generated the current page.

How does one get the URL-key for the current (or given) module?  Surely that mapping exists for the front controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url-value of the current module with:

```
$sf_params->get('module');  // in templates
```

and

```
$request->getParameter('module');       // either this
$this->getRequestParameter('module');   // or this in the actions
```

and for constucting URLs to other modules I can use [url_for()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_url_for), though I couldn't get the module url-value alone via this method (it generates an entire url).

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact value as it was written in the url you can use [custom routings](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System).  In symfony you can create a routing rule with the *module name* as a variable in the url.  This variable named whatever you want will then be available in your action.

For example (`app/*yourAppName*/config/routing.yml`):

```
the_name_of_your_route:
  url:    thisIsAUrl/:variableYouWantWithWhateverCase
  param:  { module: yourModuleName, action: yourActionName }
```

Your `url:` param can even have regEx and wildcards in them if you like.

So now when you are in your `executeYourActionName` function a variable named `variableYouWantWithWhateverCase` will be set in the request exactly how it was typed in the url.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is excellent info, Yzmir, though a little beyond what I'm trying to do at the moment.  I have the feeling this will come in quite useful later, though - thanks!